# custom button with multiple images

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have 3 images that i would like to use them to generate my custom button. my images are left.png 5x20, right.png 5x20 and mid.png 1x20. my mid.png must be repeated as long as my text lenght. how can i generate it in iphone application on the fly?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the leftCapWidth property on UIImage. You need to combine the images into a single PNG file, and then tell it the pixel width of the left part using that  property. Then when that UIImage is drawn, it'll resize correctly.

Comment: i am a newbie about iphone and objective-c, could you send me code.
thanks.